# Modify the spatial resolution of a file from an atmospheric model (Meso-NH), to compare it with another netCDF file

Tags: python, resolution, netcdf

I carried out simulations with an atmospheric model intended for research (Meso-NH), and the output files are netCDF (.nc) files.

I want to compare a variable contained in my file coming from Meso-NH with a variable contained in another netCDF file. Unfortunately, the files do not have the same structure, and I cannot easily modify my file from Meso-NH.

This is what my file from the template looks like :

```
ncdump -h /home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/albedo/re_albedo_12mnh_200618.nc
netcdf re_albedo_12mnh_200618 {
dimensions:
    ni = 182 ;
    nj = 224 ;
variables:
    double longitude(nj, ni) ;
        longitude:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        longitude:long_name = "longitude" ;
        longitude:units = "degrees_east" ;
        longitude:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lon" ;
    double latitude(nj, ni) ;
        latitude:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        latitude:long_name = "latitude" ;
        latitude:units = "degrees_north" ;
        latitude:_CoordinateAxisType = "Lat" ;
    double ni(ni) ;
        ni:standard_name = "projection_x_coordinate" ;
        ni:long_name = "x-dimension of the grid" ;
        ni:units = "m" ;
        ni:axis = "X" ;
    double nj(nj) ;
        nj:standard_name = "projection_y_coordinate" ;
        nj:long_name = "y-dimension of the grid" ;
        nj:units = "m" ;
        nj:axis = "Y" ;
    double TALB_ISBA(nj, ni) ;
        TALB_ISBA:long_name = "TALB_ISBA" ;
        TALB_ISBA:coordinates = "latitude longitude" ;
        TALB_ISBA:_FillValue = 9.96920996838687e+36 ;
        TALB_ISBA:missing_value = 9.96920996838687e+36 ;
        TALB_ISBA:grid = 4 ;
        TALB_ISBA:comment = "total albedo over tile nature (-)" ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :history = "Thu Aug 04 13:29:39 2022: cdo sellonlatbox,-6,-3,47,49.5 albedo_12_200618.nc re_albedo_12_200618.nc\nThu Aug  4 13:29:23 2022: ncks -v TALB_ISBA NLRE3.1.SEG01.012.nc albedo_12_200618.nc\n2022-03-21T18:52:59-0000: MESONH-LXifort-R8I4-MNH-V5-4-2-MON_DOSSIER-MPIAUTO-O2" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.7 COMODO-1.4" ;
        :MNH_REAL = "8" ;
        :MNH_INT = "4" ;
        :MNH_cleanly_closed = "yes" ;
        :NCO = "netCDF Operators version 4.9.2 (Homepage = http://nco.sf.net, Code = http://github.com/nco/nco)" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
```

This is what my other file looks like :

```
ncdump -h re_alb20juin.nc
netcdf re_alb20juin {
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
    lon = 720 ;
    lat = 600 ;
variables:
    int time(time) ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "days since 2000-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
    double lon(lon) ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
    double lat(lat) ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
    short Albedo_BSA_shortwave(time, lat, lon) ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:long_name = "Albedo_BSA_shortwave" ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:units = "reflectance, no units" ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:add_offset = 0. ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:scale_factor = 0.001 ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:_FillValue = 32767s ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:missing_value = 32767s ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:scale_factor_err = 0. ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:add_offset_err = 0. ;
        Albedo_BSA_shortwave:calibrated_nt = 5 ;
    short BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave(time, lat, lon) ;
        BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave:long_name = "BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave" ;
        BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave:units = "concatenated flags" ;
        BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave:_FillValue = 255s ;
        BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave:missing_value = 255s ;
        BRDF_Albedo_Band_Mandatory_Quality_shortwave:Description = "Mandatory QA:\n  0 = processed, good quality (full BRDF inversions)\n  1 = processed, see other QA (magnitude BRDF inversions)\n" ;

// global attributes:
        :CDI = "Climate Data Interface version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdi)" ;
        :history = "Thu Aug 04 13:26:41 2022: cdo sellonlatbox,-6,-3,47,49.5 /home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/alb_20juin.nc re_alb20juin.nc\nSee README.md" ;
        :source = "AppEEARS v3.7" ;
        :institution = "Land Processes Distributed Active Archive Center (LP DAAC)" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.6" ;
        :title = "MCD43A3.006 for aid0001" ;
        :references = "See README.md" ;
        :CDO = "Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)" ;
```

I want to modify the grid of the 1st file which has a spatial resolution (latitude, longitude) of 1.5km, into a grid of 500m resolution. My second file has a 500m resolution grid

Indeed, eventually I want to make the difference between the albedo (TALB_ISBA(nj, ni)) of my model and the satellite abedo (Albedo_BSA_shortwave(time, lat, lon)).
Unfortunately the composition of the files is very different and I'm a little lost, I can't do what I want. To manipulate netcdf files on python I use xarray module :

```
sat_file=xr.open_dataset('/home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/albedo/re_albedo_12mnh_200618.nc')

model_file=xr.open_dataset('/home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/albedo/re_re_albedo_12mnh_200618.nc')

sat_file
Out[55]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (ni: 182, nj: 224)
Coordinates:
    longitude  (nj, ni) float64 ...
    latitude   (nj, ni) float64 ...
  * ni         (ni) float64 3.75e+04 3.875e+04 4e+04 ... 2.625e+05 2.638e+05
  * nj         (nj) float64 3.25e+04 3.375e+04 3.5e+04 ... 3.1e+05 3.112e+05
Data variables:
    TALB_ISBA  (nj, ni) float64 ...
Attributes:
    CDI:                 Climate Data Interface version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet...
    history:             Thu Aug 04 13:29:39 2022: cdo sellonlatbox,-6,-3,47,...
    Conventions:         CF-1.7 COMODO-1.4
    MNH_REAL:            8
    MNH_INT:             4
    MNH_cleanly_closed:  yes
    NCO:                 netCDF Operators version 4.9.2 (Homepage = http://nc...
    CDO:                 Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet...

model_file
Out[58]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (ni: 182, nj: 224)
Coordinates:
    longitude  (nj, ni) float64 ...
    latitude   (nj, ni) float64 ...
  * ni         (ni) float64 3.75e+04 3.875e+04 4e+04 ... 2.625e+05 2.638e+05
  * nj         (nj) float64 3.25e+04 3.375e+04 3.5e+04 ... 3.1e+05 3.112e+05
Data variables:
    TALB_ISBA  (nj, ni) float64 ...
Attributes:
    CDI:                 Climate Data Interface version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet...
    history:             Thu Aug 04 13:29:39 2022: cdo sellonlatbox,-6,-3,47,...
    Conventions:         CF-1.7 COMODO-1.4
    MNH_REAL:            8
    MNH_INT:             4
    MNH_cleanly_closed:  yes
    NCO:                 netCDF Operators version 4.9.2 (Homepage = http://nc...
    CDO:                 Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet...
```

Do you have a solution please?
My level in computer science is quite limited, so if possible a fairly simple technique.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this in Python. Since the files appear to have been cropped using CDO, you might want to try using my package nctoolkit (which uses CDO as a backend). To regrid one file to another's grid, you would just need to do the following:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data("/home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/albedo/re_albedo_12mnh_200618.nc")
ds.regrid('/home/mcms/le-galln/Téléchargements/albedo/re_re_albedo_12mnh_200618.nc')
```

If you wanted to export this to xarray you could do this:

```
ds_xr = ds.to_xarray()
```

By default nctoolkit uses bilinear interpolation, which is probably sufficient for your purposes. However, you might want to try other regridding methods, such as nearest neighbour: https://nctoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/nctoolkit.DataSet.regrid.html?highlight=regrid#nctoolkit.DataSet.regrid